# Which of the OreImo endings followed the light novels?

Tags: oreimo

The anime adaptation for Ore no Imouto ga Konnani Kawaii Wake ga Nai had two endings, which branched off after episode 11 (the "good end" vs the "true end"). Of course, these couldn't both have happened in the light novels because they aren't consistent with each other. Which one of these follows the light novels closer, i.e. in the novels,

> does Kirino go to America or stay in Japan?

I suppose there's also the possibility that these are both anime-original content.

Comment: The question is rather confusing actually. Kirino did go to America for a while. Later Kyousuke go to America to take her back to Japan and she went back with him. This happens not only in the Anime but also in the Light Novel. So, what do you mean by "good end" and "true end"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "true end" of OreImo anime follows the novel (and quite closely at that). This short excerpt from Volume 5 Chapter 4 answers the question.

> But the mail I got from my little sister betrayed my expectations.
>
>  **Please throw away my entire collection that I’ve entrusted to you.**
>
>  That was the only sentence written.

Comment: What about OreImo 2's ending?

Comment: @ErikHumphrey: It adapts the entire series, with quite a lot of content cut off in behind. The cut off content, as far as I heard from people who have read, are not very good, so I guess you don't miss much here.